# What is use of enabled(snapshot, releases) tag in maven pom's repository element?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

When specifying the repository element why we need `snapshots` and  `releases` as well?

Example:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>my-repo</id>
  <url>https://some.url.com/my-repo</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false/true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false/true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
```

How it affects a specific version of the dependency? (1.2.3-SNAPSHOT, 1.2.3, 1.2.3-RELEASE)

When there are multiple repositories, which repository will be searched for the artifact? How the artifacts being resolved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When specifying the repository element why we need false/true and   as well?

We need to do so if we would like to have a repository only for released versions, for instance, and another one only for SNAPSHOT versions.

This is a common use case for enterprise Maven repositories (i.e. Nexus, Artifactory, Archivia), when certain versions (like SNAPSHOT) are only available in a repository (deployed but a CI job, as an example) while released versions would only be available in another repository. A CI job releasing something for PROD should only use the latter repository, not using/allowing any SNAPSHOT version and breaking the build otherwise (enforcing build reproducibility and good practices).

From [official Maven Settings documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)

> **releases**, **snapshots**: These are the policies for each type of artifact, Release or snapshot. With these two sets, a POM has the power to alter the policies for each type independent of the other within a single repository. For example, one may decide to enable only snapshot downloads, possibly for development purposes.
>
> **enabled**: `true` or `false` for whether this repository is enabled for the respective type (`releases` or `snapshots`).

---

> When there are multiple repositories , which repository will be searched for the artifact? How the artifacts being resolved?

The order of declaration will affect the look up order used by Maven. Check this [official Maven ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400) providing the fix for the proper behavior from version **3.0** on.

- [**MNG-4400**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4400): **Repository order from settings.xml is not respected during artifact resolution**

---

> How it affects a specific version of the dependency? (1.2.3-SNAPSHOT, 1.2.3, 1.2.3-RELEASE)

Merging the two answers above, depending on the order of declaration and which repository allow which type of artifact (snapshot or not).

---

Further references:

- [Maven: working with multiple repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)
- [Maven Settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)
- [Maven: introduction to repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Comment: A SNAPSHOT versioned artifact will be searched in the SNAPSHOT enabled repositories in the order of repository declarations?

Comment: @Selva yes, that's correct. Moreover a SNAPSHOTs will be updated according to the `updatePolicy` element value or forced via the command line `-U` option

Comment: What is the default value for a repository of respective type as Release. I mean if i don't specify <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases> and I have enabled snapshot. Then is that repo not available for release or is there any default value?

Comment: Why oh why could they not have learned about XML attributes before they started designing the pom.xml?  How much more concisely it could have been written, eg. `<snapshots enabled="true"/>` or even `<repository id="whatever" snapshots="true">` ...

Comment: For info on the defaults, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684312/in-a-maven-repository-entry-in-the-pom-are-snapshots-enabled-by-default