# In a Maven repository entry in the POM, are snapshots enabled by default?

Tags: java, maven

A Maven [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) may define a "repository". For example,

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

What if I don't declare `<snapshots>` or `<releases>`? What are the defaults?  They seem optional...

According to *[How does a Maven repository work?](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/)*

`<releases>` is enabled by default on all repositories.  I assume `<snapshots>` is disabled by default? So is the above snippet redundant?

Comment: As a note, `mvn help:effective-pom` may be useful in figuring out questions relating to defaults.

Comment: OK I tried `mvn help:effective-pom` but for whatever reason it just collapses down repositories "to the defaults" like `<repository>
      <id>centrallll</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>` but I could compare that with what I specified to see which ones it views as "not default", good idea!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, snapshots are enabled by default if we configure a `<repository>` in `pom.xml`**

If we think through, even when we don't specify any `<repository>` in our `pom.xml` file, Maven downloads the artifacts from the default repository. This is because the default 'Central' repository is configured in the [Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM).

An excerpt from Super POM's page:

> Similar to the inheritance of objects in object oriented programming,
> POMs that extend a parent POM inherit certain values from that parent.
> Moreover, just as Java objects ultimately inherit from
> java.lang.Object, all Project Object Models inherit from a base Super
> POM. The snippet below is the Super POM for Maven 3.5.4.
>
> ````xml
>     <repository>
>         <id>central</id>
>         <name>Central Repository</name>
>         <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
>         <layout>default</layout>
>         <snapshots>
>             <enabled>false</enabled>
>         </snapshots>
>     </repository> </repositories> ```
> ````

Because of this configuration, `snapshot` downloads 'by default' only 'from the central Maven repository' are disabled.

**But if we specify `<repository>` in our `pom.xml`, then by default the `snapshots` are `enabled`**. You can find the default value of `enabled` as `true` here:

[image]

All that being said, I recommend we set that so that other developers would 'get' why their `snapshot` JAR file is not downloaded from [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). It provides more clarity and given that it's not exposed other than in the codebase, it doesn't 'harm' anyone.

Comment: Hmm I understand that all pom's inherit from the "super" pom (so they have that repository...defined), but if I define new repositories...it's not saying new repositories inherit from the super POM's repository I don't think.  I guess it's just implied default false...,maybe the super pom is trying to teach us "these is how it is by default" :)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to look up. Looks like the default value for `<enabled>` under `<snapshot>` is `true`. You can try that out in Eclipse suggestions if you try with a sample repository tag. Sample here: https://imgur.com/rbkmEJB. So looks like the rule is, if we don't override, it's disabled by default through Super POM. If we have a repository configured, snapshot is enabled by default.

Comment: OK I added a repo without `snapshots` specified, and ran `mvn -X` which showed this: `Repositories (dependencies): [... , my_new_repo (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases+snapshots)` so it appears you're right, if it isn't specified, it defaults to true, thanks for the help!

Comment: Exactly! Thanks to you too for pointing out. I'm currently working on updating my answer with much more details for clarity :)

Comment: @rogerdpack, I've made a complete overhaul to my initial answer. Let me know if we've covered everything w.r.t the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation does not explicitly state any default setting: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories

So I assume the current "default" behavior is just "what is the easiest way for the developer to implement it" and this may change in the future when new features are added.

So if you want to be safe, then explicitly state what you want.

Comment: I love it when they don't document anything...gah :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

- **releases**: Default value is: **true**.
- **snapshots**:  Default value is: **true**.

Check the official documentation:  https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.2/maven-settings/settings.html

#### releases

Download policy

| Element | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `enabled` | `boolean` | Whether to use this repository for downloading this type of artifact. **Default value is**: `true`. |
| `updatePolicy` | `String` | The frequency for downloading updates - can be "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never" (only if it doesn't exist locally). |
| `checksumPolicy` | `String` | What to do when verification of an artifact checksum fails - warn, fail, etc. Valid values are "fail" or "warn". |

#### snapshots

Download policy

| Element | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `enabled` | `boolean` | Whether to use this repository for downloading this type of artifact. **Default value is**: `true`. |
| `updatePolicy` | `String` | The frequency for downloading updates - can be "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never" (only if it doesn't exist locally). |
| `checksumPolicy` | `String` | What to do when verification of an artifact checksum fails - warn, fail, etc. Valid values are "fail" or "warn". |

Comment: Ahh there is a second section of documentation for it.  You cracked the maven documentation code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Default value for `<enabled />` tag is `true`,
but the `<snapshots>` tag is not there by default.

Repository managers like Nexus OSS (developed by the same company as maven itself) usually have repositories specially for releases and for snapshots.
Even if (experienced) Nexus admin put repositories into groups, then there should be group for release versions and group for snapshot versions.

Note that maven will look for check within snapshot repositories only when looking for snapshot dependency
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5907727/482717

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <name>Nexus Releases</name>
      <id>releases-repo</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled />
      </snapshots>
      <name>Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <id>snapshots-repo</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>


  </repositories>
```

And you want as build master is usually clear control, whether your project is using only release version (and so is more stable) or is using snapshot versions (and so can break with any next build).
As an advise, stay out of maven snapshot for own artifacts and for external, they complicate things too much, not worth it.

Keep things simple in your build, and demand so for other teams you depend on.